# Wicket: form submit with reusable components and AjaxButton

Tags: ajax, wicket

I'm using wicket version 6.

I have a form. as contents of the form, I have a *FormComponentPanel* that contains two *DateTimeField*'s (*org.apache.wicket.extensions.yui.calendar*).

In the class containing the form I have one AjaxButton, and one AjaxLink, both doing the same: reading the models, creating a new object and sending it to some server for processing.

Anyhow,

- when clicking on the Link my new object is created with the correct values **except** those newly dates selected with the datepicker
- when clicking the Button I get some error (**[AjaxRequestHandler@1701777932 responseObject [org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestHandler$1@3e1]**) but no further information on the error

well, I addressed the first issue (Link) with trying to add ajax update behavior to it, as suggested [here](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/DateField-and-AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior-in-wicket-1-5-5-td4551607.html) , but the selected date is not updated in the model

the AjaxButton is created and *onSubmit* overwritten with just calling another method and *target.add(form)*; also *setOutputMarkupId* is set to **true**, but it seems that still something is missing

In order to get it to work I'd just need to solve one of the problems, but it would be great if someone has a solution for both problems. Thanks in advance.

**edit**

```
public MyPanelIncludingForm() {
  // ...
  form.add(getRangePanel()); // creates a new TimeRangePanel and returns the instance
  form.add(getSubmitButton());
  // ...
}

private FormComponent<String> getSubmitButton() {
  FormComponent<String> submitBtn = new AjaxButton("submitBtn", form) {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3005L;

    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
      System.out.println("submit QT ajax button");
      setResponsePage(HomePage.class);
      sendQuery();
      target.add(form);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
      System.err.println("error occurred. " + target);
      target.add(feedback);
    }
  };
  submitBtn.setOutputMarkupId(true);
  return submitBtn;
}

// separate FormComponentModel for timeRange

public class TimeRangePanel extends FormComponentPanel<MyRange> {

MyRange range;
PropertyModel<Date> dpFromPM = new PropertyModel<Date>(this, "range.start");
PropertyModel<Date> dpToPM = new PropertyModel<Date>(this, "range.stop");
public RangePanel(String id, IModel<MyRange> model) {
  super(id, model);

dpFrom = new DateTimeField("dpFrom", dpFromPM) {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3006L;

  @Override
  protected DateTextField newDateTextField(String id, PropertyModel<Date> model) {

    DateTextField dtf = super.newDateTextField(id, model);

    AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior a = new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onChange") {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 3006L;
      @Override
      protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        System.out.println("here u " + dpFrom.getModelObject().toString());
      }
    };
    dtf.add(a);
    return dtf;
  }
};

// second DateTimeField as dpFrom

} // end of constructor

@Override
protected void onBeforeRender() {
  range = getModelObject();
  super.onBeforeRender();
}

} // end of class
```

**edit2**

this is what the wicket ajax debug window is printing:

```
INFO: focus removed from 
INFO: focus set on submitBtn11
INFO: Received ajax response (299 characters)
INFO:
<div wicket:id="feedbackQuery" class="feedback" id="feedbackQuery1c"><wicket:panel>
  <ul wicket:id="feedbackul" class="feedbackPanel">
    <li wicket:id="messages" class="feedbackPanelERROR">
      <span wicket:id="message" class="feedbackPanelERROR"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</wicket:panel></div>
INFO: returned focused element: [object HTMLInputElement]
INFO: returned focused element: [object HTMLInputElement]
INFO: Response processed successfully.
INFO: refocus last focused component not needed/allowed
INFO: focus removed from submitBtn11
```

**edit3**

As I wrote in a comment:

I removed the re-usable components (*FormComponentPanel*) and now I don't get an error with the AjaxButton . anyhow, it's weird, I thought re-usable components should work, even with Ajax; also the models were assigned properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when clicking the Button I get some error
>   ([AjaxRequestHandler@1701777932 responseObject
>   [org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxRequestHandler$1@3e1]) but no further
>   information on the error

=> You should run Wicket in DEVELOPMENT mode to get a more detailed trace.

You might simply add in your form a field called:

range.start

range.stop

and use the Object MyRange as property model instead create a new one for each field.
There is actually no need for that extra cycle. And I don't think Wicket will write the information back to the MyRange object if you create new PropertyModels for every attribute.

For example: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/web/components/admin/users/UserForm.java?view=markup
Line 276

and the corresponding HTML
http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/incubator/openmeetings/trunk/singlewebapp/src/org/apache/openmeetings/web/components/admin/users/UsersPanel.html?view=markup
Line 82

Sebastian

Comment: thanks for the reply. i'm running wicket in DEV mode.
I wanted to build a re-usable component that can handle time ranges, thus I reference the bean (MyRange), that I passed as model, to the new FormComponent. but anyhow, I'm trying to do all in the same class, but I don't think that this way _should_ be the final solution

Comment: Then you have more trace then just this single line. Wicket normally has excellent trace and error messages.

Comment: and no, there is no further output (neither in console nor on the webpage when i add it to the feedback panel). I was running in DEV mode earlier as well

Comment: i added the debug information logged into "wicket ajax debug window"

Comment: *but the selected date is not updated in the model* => What Model are you talking about. You actually have 3 models. MyRange would never be updated as long as you don't assign this model to the fields. I also miss that you add "dpFrom" to the actually FormComponent. You initialize it in the constructor but you add it nowwhere. Only the parent is added. But maybe this is just hard to understand based on the code snippets.

Comment: thanks again for the reply. I removed the re-usable components (_FormComponentPanel_) and now I don't get an error with the _AjaxButton_ . anyhow, it' weird, I thought re-usable components should work, even with Ajax; couldn't find any other problem as the models were assigned properly. anyhow, maybe it's just me. thanks again.